# Error showing images in a jsf page after implements spring security

Tags: jsp, jsf, spring-security

I have a a jsf applicattion that shows an image from hard disk using a servlet, now I´m starting to use  spring security and I moved my xhtml files to another folders. Now the browser can´t find the images.

in the servlet I have defined the mapping url with "/file"

After the folder change when I try to display Im getting this WARNING

```
No mime type could be found for file /secured/file/repositorio/48/55/56/351/352.jsp
```

the image url showed by the chrome ispector is

```
http://localhost:8080/WSysGED/secured/file/repositorio/48/55/56/351/352.jpg?pfdrid_c=true
```

but if I type this ulr

```
http://localhost:8080/WSysGED/file/repositorio/48/55/56/351/352.jpg?pfdrid_c=true
```

the image is showed in the browser

I dont understand why the  /secured/ in the url makes diference, because the servlet mapping is after /file

In the spring application-context-security.xml file I defined

```
<http pattern="/secured/file/**" security="none" />
```

so  that folder  dont have any access restriction

Why the images are not showed and how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance for your time and aswers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search in all the wrong places i reallized that I´m doing the  mapping servlet like this /file/* , I just moved to /secured/file/* and works.